# PIC Bootloader -- USB controller required?

Tags: embedded, usb, pic, bootloader

I am working with a simple PIC18F2550 and I'm wondering about how to get a bootloader working on it. It's a very simple device with a USB port and CDC firmware. When I download Tiny Bootloader onto the pic, my PC doesn't recognize the device. Do I NEED to have a USB controller in my circuit in order for it to work? Such as the MAX232? 
Would the same apply to the PIC32MX795F512L?

Thanks!

Comment: A MAX232 is definitively not am USB-Controller, but just a level-converter.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So do I require a level-converter in order to run a bootloader?

Comment: Just corrected about the MAX. No idea what about the PIC. However, I would suggest you have a look at microchip. Normally such MCUs do require a JTAG-interface or similar. Microchip used to have their own interface, but I'm not familar with the PICs anymore (luckily). Normally there is no bootloader; it all works much more basic, but that rule has become less general. If you are planning actual embedded development, you will, however, not get along with just a bootload, as you will **verrrry** likely also need to debug remotely. If you're not familar with all this, I urge you to get the basics

Comment: Don't start building a house from the rooftop. Oh, and PIC32 is s completely different architecture. Really: first get the basics right - no offense, you just don't do yourself a favour the other way 'round!

Comment: Well, thanks. I already use a JTAG to get my own CDC firmware onto the PIC. I'm really just wondering about using bootloaders via USB instead of having to use the pins every time. If anyone can offer insight into that, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Well, the reference-manual (Microchips might just have a datasheet with all in) should state clear if there is a bootloader or not and include the protocol (or reference an application-note). For the STM32F for instance, there is actually one in an extra ROM. But that is a much bigger beast than PIC18.

Comment: You should include a link to the boot loader you are referring to; I imagine that there have been many bootloaders referred to as 'tiny'.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear from the [Tiny PIC boot loader documentation](http://www.etc.ugal.ro/cchiculita/software/tinybldusage.htm) that it expects a UART connection rather than USB (that is what the MAX232 is for - it is an RS232 line driver).

You could simply do that and use an external serial to USB converter thus saving the code space required by the USB-CDC stack.  Otherwise you will have to modify the boot loader code to use the CDC driver rather than the UART.

You will have to link the USB code with the boot loader, which will no doubt significantly increase its size. You may need therefore also to move the application start address to accommodate the boot loader. Furthermore, if the application needs USB comms, you may need a separate copy of the code in the application unless you provide a method of accessing the bootloader code from the application; which is possible, but not necessarily straightforward.

All that said, note the part at the end of the end of the page about extending the bootloader;  On the face of it it seems unsuited to extension.  Without looking at the code and its memory map, it is not clear why it has this constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The PIC18F2550 has a USB interface built into it.  It is called the "USB SIE" and there is a large section in the datasheet that documents it.  If you make the right electrical connections, you should be able to connect your PIC18F2550 directly to a USB port without any active electronics between them.  There is no reason you would need extra USB hardware just because you want to run a bootloader.

If you want to troubleshoot your problems with the bootloader, you should probably post another question with more details.  It could be a problem with the PIC's configuration bits or something like that.  I recommend trying to modify the bootloader to get it to blink an LED as a basic first step just so you can verify that you were able to get its code to run at all.